# Django sitemap - double http:// in front of URL

Tags: python, django, sitemap

In Django 1.4.12, I have a Sitemap class:

```
class MySitemap(Sitemap):
    def items(self):
        return ['/my/url1/',
                '/my/url2/',]

    def location(self, obj):
        return str(obj)
```

and in urls.py

```
sitemaps = {
            'global': MySitemap,
            }

...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

However, my generate sitemap.xml has `http://http://` in front of it, such as:

```
...
<url><loc>http://http://mywebsite.com/my/url1</loc></url>
...
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably included `http://` in your `Site` object's  domain name from the sites framework (`django.contrib.sites`). Remove it.

This field should only include the actual domain name, not the protocol, as the protocol itself can change (e.g. to `https://`).