# Strange url constructed by Django

Tags: python, django

In development phase (Django 1.9 and Virtualbox with Linux was used) there was no problems with links. In production server (Django 1.8.9 is used as fastcgi is supported) links are not working. Only opening page is shown. Link is shown in this way:
http://rationale.ee.klient.veebimajutus.ee/http%3A//rationale.ee.klient.veebimajutus.ee/about
And in Page not found message is written:
Request URL:    http://http://rationale.ee.klient.veebimajutus.ee/http:/rationale.ee.klient.veebimajutus.ee/news
The current URL, http:/rationale.ee.klient.veebimajutus.ee/about, didn't match any of these.

It should be a setup problem. Any hints what should I do? Why utf8 symbols are shown?

Comment: As a side note, it is a _very_ good idea to match your development Django version to your production Django version. There are [significant changes between 1.8 and 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django sitemap - double http:// in front of URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790009/django-sitemap-double-http-in-front-of-url)

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790009/django-sitemap-double-http-in-front-of-url) answer. Probably you included `http://` in your `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` object, hovewer it need to be ONLY domain.

Here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site)

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate then you should leave a comment to that duplicate.

Comment: @Sayse sure, mate. But i am not sure if it is a duplicate. But i got you, if i think so - i flag.

Answer (score 0):

It was missing line in settings.py:
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ''
After it urls are ok